# Get Path in asp.net for c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get a path for a file which a users uploads but the path that I am getting is wrong because the path should be for an example

```
 "C:\\Users\\Tranga.Patel\\Downloads\template.xlsx"
```

but on my program I get

```
 "c:\\windows\\system32\\inetsrv\\Template Final.xlsx"
```

the code that I am using is

```
fileName = Path.GetFullPath(fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
```

I also tried using

```
 fileName = Server.MapPath(Path.GetFullPath(fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName));
```

this give the directory of the project

Comment: The fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName will give a full path in internet explorer, but other browsers will only give the name of the file. Or arent you working on a website?

Comment: i am working on a webiste but the browser that i am using is chrome.. but people should be using any browser and the code should still work.

Comment: Could you tell me why you want to have the path of the client? When the file is posted to the server you can't get the path of the client properly. Moreover, you shouldnt need that path at all.

Comment: the sile is not saved on the actual sever

Comment: You mean its a local project? I'm trying to help, but i don't understand why you want to use the clients path.

Comment: multiple users will be using the program at once and they may have the same fiel name and therefore i can not upload their file to the server and have to keep it o0n there local folders.

Comment: So if i'm correct: Your program is a website with the ability to upload a file. The website will be accessed by multiple users. You have a upload component but you want to keep the file on the local folders of the users. The purpose of an upload component is to tranfer a file to the server. It's not possible to make a link to the local file by using an upload component.

Comment: nah.. becuase its a excel file which i am reading onto a datatable..and the code that u found would not work because it give the project file directory and the file is not on that

Comment: @user1776590 - Your question does not make sense.  The two filenames are not even the same.  So you are not even uploading the file, or at the very least, saving it on the server storage swap?  You do understand that the class your using UPLOADS and SAVES the files right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a File Upload control? If you are, you just need them to select the document they want to upload and then specify the path you want to save it at. For example

```
 // Get File Name
 documentName = Path.GetFileName(fuContentDocuments.FileName);

 // Specify your server path
 string serverPath = Server.MapPath("../../" + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString());

// The final path
string fileLocation = (serverPath + "\\" + userId + "\\" + documentName);

// if folder doesn't exist then create it
if (!Directory.Exists(serverPath + "\\" + userId + "\\"))
{
    // create the folder for the file
    Directory.CreateDirectory(serverPath + "\\" + userId + "\\");
}

// Upload the file
fuContentDocuments.SaveAs(fileLocation);
```

Note: UserId is just the users login userId. This way other users wont override it.

Answer (score 2):

try using following:

```
var path=Server.MapPath('Uploads folder path from root directory');
```

This gives you the folder path from the root directory of your website.

EDIT:- You should be knowing to which path users are saving the file if it is not in your site directory tree.

Comment: this also give the root directory of the actual project and not the path that a user would upload that data from

Comment: the file can be saved anywhere in the users direcory and i will be having multiple users using this program at once and cant have the same file uploaded twice